# Managing updates and versions for multiple Java versions

Tags: java, version-control

I have multiple java versions. I have both the 64 and 32 bit JRE versions of 8, the JDK from version 8 for programming purposes, and what appears to be a 32 bit Java 7 JRE for some older apps I have.

I think the auto-updater is only updating the JRE versions of 8. How do I manage this mess? I have a feeling I can get rid of one of the JRE versions of 8, any tips on that? I'm running 64-bit Win 10.

Comment: Did you write those “older apps”?  It takes some significant effort to write code that works in Java 7 but not in Java 8.

Comment: Nope. I don't remember myself which apps they are, I just remember coming across a specific request for 7 some time ago.